# Requested Operation requires elevation VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have set my Visual Studio to run as Admin (by changing running the troubleshoot compatibility on VSLauncher.exe) always. Now, if I try to open a folder in visual studio, by right clicking on the folder and selecting Open in Visual Studio, I receive the message "Requested Operation requires elevation". How to solve this by having VS run as Admin all the time but able to open any folder in VS by right clicking. Please Help.